# How to set constraints for Xib for dynamic height of a cell...?

Tags: swift, autolayout

[image: my xib for dynamic height]

I am using xib to display the data but if the data for labels are empty am hiding the labels but height of the cell is not decreasing based on the contents.Thanks in advance your suggestions are helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic UITableView row height using UIStackView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238662/dynamic-uitableview-row-height-using-uistackview)

Comment: try stackView , or adding a constraint and reduce the constant of them to 0 instead of hiding it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Answer (score 0):

You should use auto layout constarits, 
not set a fixed height for labels please connect to top and bottom

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```